# android listview with actionmode

Tags: android

In my android app, there is listview which gets populated from cursor(db). It has multiple choice enabled and actionbarsherlock's actionmode with actions on selected items.

I am stuck at this scenario,

I select two items from listview and action mode says two items selected. Now if I click back, then action mode finishes but checkeditem stays checked. How to uncheck all of them on back key keeping in mind that listview.getChildCount() will only return visible items?

```
    private static SparseBooleanArray checkedItemsArray;

    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3)
{
        boolean isOneRowChecked = false;
    CheckableRelativeLayout r;
    checkedItemsArray = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        r = (CheckableRelativeLayout) listView.getChildAt(i);

        if (r != null && r.isChecked())
        {
            r.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            isOneRowChecked = true;
        } else
        {
            r.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
    mActionMode = OtherActivity.this.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);

    if (!isOneRowChecked && mActionMode != null)
    {
        mActionMode.finish();
        checkedItemsArray = null;
    }

}
```

My activity is also implementing OnScrollListener, so

```
    @Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
{
    int i = firstVisibleItem;
    if (checkedItemsArray != null)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < visibleItemCount; k++)
        {

            CheckableRelativeLayout r = (CheckableRelativeLayout) listView.getChildAt(k);
            if (checkedItemsArray.get(i))
            {
                r.setChecked(true);
                r.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            } else
            {
                r.setChecked(false);
                r.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < visibleItemCount; k++)
        {
            listView.setItemChecked(k, false);
            CheckableRelativeLayout r = (CheckableRelativeLayout) listView.getChildAt(k);
            r.setChecked(false);
            r.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you do this in onDestroyActionMode :

```
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
  listView.clearChoices();
  for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    ((Checkable) listView.getChildAt(i)).setChecked(false);
  }
  listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);

}
```

Comment: But onDestroyActionMode is called everytime when listview selection changes ??

Comment: onDestroyActionMode is called when an action mode is about to be exited and destroyed so just make sure that in your onCreateActionMode you are calling         listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);